# How to build jar file with gradle with dependencies

Tags: java, exception, gradle, jar

I'm building a jar file with Gradle. This jar file is being used as a library in another project. But when the project tries to use the jar file, a ClassNotFoundException is returned.

```
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/auth0/jwt/JWT
```

I've included the jwt library in the gradle file building the jar:

```
  compile group: 'com.auth0', name: 'java-jwt', version: '3.4.0'
```

The project using the jar can't seem to find this jar dependency in the jar.

I built the jar with the gradle command:

```
 task fatJar(type: Jar) {
     manifest {
         attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Jar File creation',
            'Implementation-Version': version,
            'Main-Class': 'com.group.me.name.MyJarClass'
     }
     baseName = project.name + '-all'
     from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
     with jar
     exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
  }
```

How do I include the missing dependency in the jar?

Comment: Just using google with `gradle fat jar dependencies` showed me some interesting links ...

Answer (score 0):

You, generally, should not pack the dependencies inside a published JAR. It's better to declare them as dependencies in `pom.xml` and let the user of you JAR fetch them. It's just a good practice that should be enough.

If it's not enough, use [Gradle Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '4.0.2'
}
```

Fat JAR is produced with `shadowJar` task in this case. Publishing is easy as well:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        shadow(MavenPublication) { publication ->
            project.shadow.component(publication)
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "http://your.repo"
        }
    }
}
```